# on unmounting of component not getting the state value

Tags: reactjs

I have a state variable where i am having the value, so on before unmounting i need to log this to some analytics. So when i access the state it shows me as undefined. So before unmount i need to get this data.

```
const [name, setName] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    console.log(name) // null
  }
}, [])

<input value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
```

here the last value before mounting i am not getting. How can i get this value before mounting happens

Answer (score 4):

In our project we are using a custom hook **useIsMounted** for that purpose: (we did not invent this - there are lot's of sources to be found). By using the standard useEffect logic with name as dependency, every keystroke will cause the code to trigger, which was not desirable in our case. We just wanted a single trigger on unmount.

```
import {useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

//custom hook outside the component to detect unmount
export default function useIsMounted() {
    const isMounted = useRef(false)
    useEffect(() => {
        isMounted.current = true
        return () => {
            isMounted.current = false
        }
    }, [])
    return () => isMounted.current
}
```

storing that under hooks/mounted.js you can use it like in this example

```
import useIsMounted from '../hooks/mounted'

export default function AnyComp() {

    const mounted = useIsMounted()

    const [name, setName] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('AnyComp mounted')
        return () => {
            if (!mounted()) {
                console.log('AnyComp unmounted', name)
            }
        };
    }, [mounted])

    return (
        <input value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
    )
}
```

The console.log now should reflect the actual value of your state variable!

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `name` as dependency at `useEffect` so that react runs the effect when name state value is updated. Also while unmounting it would have the latest state bind for name property.

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log(name);
    }
  }, [name]);
```

You can read about useEffect at [react.org](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the function gets called every time 'name' changes. The answer by Byron Star is better.

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency in hooks as it will change when you start typing and useEffect clean up function will give you last state

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log(name);
    }
}, [name]);
```